# How do I calibrate a Totaline thermostat?

Tags: thermostat, air-conditioning

Our thermostat is not reading correctly

[image: wrong reading]

how can I calibrate it? I searched the [Totaline site](http://www.totaline.com.au/product-category/air-conditioners/) and it seems like this particular product is not listed (and I can not find the model of this product), and all the instructions of holding down one of several keys did not work for us. Does anyone happen to know how to calibrate this?

Also, it is showing "E3" message after my previous failed attempts

[image: e3]

Thank you in advance and it would be a great help in this cold weather...

Comment: Are you certain that 83° is what it's showing as the _current_ temperature, not the _set point_ temperature?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, I am certain, the set point temperature is 73.

Comment: Never hurts to ask the obvious questions... ;)

Comment: @Ack Do you know where is the proper place to ask this question? Thanks!